# Why my program isn't accepting the second input?

Tags: c++, cin

I don't know why it doesn't take the ***second input***. Help me solve it.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char fn,ln;
    cout<<"Enter your First Name\n"<<endl;
    cin>>fn;
    cout<<"Enter your Last Name"<<endl;
    cin>>ln;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `char` can only hold a single character.  Don't you want `std::string`?

Comment: `char fn,ln;` these variables can only store 1 character. You don't expect a person's name to be two characters!

Comment: Change `char fn,ln;` to `std::string fn,ln;` then consider some people will have 2 first names with a space between and they don't consider the second part to be their middle name. Such a person will not work with `cin>>fn;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `char` can only hold a single character, you may use `std::string` for storing names.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main( )
{
    std::cout << "Enter your first name\n";
    std::string firstName;
    std::getline( std::cin, firstName );

    std::cout << "Enter your last name\n";
    std::string lastName;
    std::getline( std::cin, lastName );

    std::cout << "\nHi " << firstName << ' ' << lastName << '\n';
}
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter your first name
John
Enter your last name
Connor

Hi John Connor
```